# Class Diagram for Social Media Platform

Tags: oop, class-diagram

In a professional social network, how would I represent connections between users? (like Linkedin) Should I create a connection class for which there would be an instance for every connection between 2 users or is that redundant? Should the user class instead have a self-association (reflexive association)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` class would have a collection of Followings:

```
public class User
{
    // ... the other code is omitted for the brevity
    public IEnumerable<User> Followings { get; set; }
}
```

So if your database has the `Following` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Followings(
    User_Id INT NOT NULL, 
    Following_Id INT NOT NULL,
    DateCreated DATE NOT NULL,
);
```

Do not forget to create constraints and foreign keys in your table. Then it is possible to have `Following` class:

```
public class Followings {
    public UserId int { get; set; }
    public FollowingId int { get; set; }
    public DateCreated DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can write easily the following query:

```
select * from Following where UserId = x.id -- or vice versa
```

Comment: So is there an instance of Followings for every connection? Or is there an instance of Followings for every instance of user?

Comment: @Jamal please, see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your help, I chose this implementation. 

Comment: Thanks for that, I will be sure to accept answers from now on!